# Transform Array of Strings to Objects

Tags: javascript, destructuring

I have an array of strings, each containing comma separated values.

I'd like to transform this into an array of objects.

For example, I have:

```
var myarray = [
 "a1,b1,c1,d1",
 "a2,b2,c2,d2",
 "a3,b3,c3,d3"
]
```

... which should end up as:

```
[
  {
    "field1": "a1",
    "field2": "b1",
    "field3": "c1",
    "field3": "d1"
  },
  {
    "field1": "a2",
    "field2": "b2",
    "field3": "c2",
    "field2": "d2"
  },
  {
    "field1": "a3",
    "field2": "b3",
    "field3": "c3",
    "field3": "d3"
  },
]
```

I've tried various approaches, like *Object.assign* and the spread operator. But it seems like there must be a simpler way to do this using destructuring or another approach.

Comment: Use Array.map(), String.split() and then Array.reduce() on the splitted array.

Comment: There's nothing in the input that corresponds to the property names. You'll need to write a loop that generates those.

Comment: you can't do this with destructuring. Destructuring is for turning an object into variables, not for iteration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
var myarray = [
 "a1,b1,c1,d1",
 "a2,b2,c2,d2",
 "a3,b3,c3,d3"
];

const makeProperties = arr => arr.map(item => item.split(',').reduce((result, splitItem, index) => {
  result['field' + (index + 1)] = splitItem;
  return result;
}, {}));

console.log(makeProperties(myarray));
```

Here is a demo of using words for numbers

```js
var myarray = [
 "a1,b1,c1,d1",
 "a2,b2,c2,d2",
 "a3,b3,c3,d3"
];

const numbers = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four'];

const makeProperties = arr => arr.map(item => item.split(',').reduce((result, splitItem, index) => {
  result[numbers[index]] = splitItem;
  return result;
}, {}));

console.log(makeProperties(myarray));
```

Comment: This is awesome! As a variation, how would I modify this if I want the fields to have completely different names (e.g., "one", "two", "three", "four")?

Comment: use the index to pull from an array ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four']

Comment: Great - thanks! That works. Interestingly, though, the fields in each resulting object end up in alphabetical order. Trying to determine now how to maintain their original order.

Comment: Object keys stay in order of insertion, it is in the ES6 spec. What do you mean fields end up in alphabetical order? I have added a second snippet to demonstrate this.

Comment: Well that's quite odd. When I copy that exact code into jsfiddle.net (where I tested), the result has the keys in alpha order, not order of insertion. See https://jsfiddle.net/ud3hjs8o/.

Comment: That is a bit weird

Answer (score 1):

You can make double [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) by mapping the array then their values and replace the default properties by the new one.

```js
var myarray = ["a1,b1,c1,d1", "a2,b2,c2,d2", "a3,b3,c3,d3"];

const fromArrayToObjects = (array) =>
  array.map((value, index) => {
    const o = Object.assign({}, value.split(","));
    Object.keys(o).map((key, i) => {
      Object.defineProperty(
        o,
        "field" + (i + 1),
        Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(o, key)
      );
      delete o[key];
    });
    return o;
  });
console.log(fromArrayToObjects(myarray));
```

Comment: This maps to an array of objects with one property, not a single object with multiple properties.

Comment: I put the code in a runnable snippet to demonstrate that the output is incorrect.

Comment: Oh, it was my mistake, I did not notice that let me fix it.

Comment: @AdrianBrand, the solution is fixed.